# How to use the two columns to get the result of third column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query

```
SELECT
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS FoodServer,
  SUM(Extended * Multiplier) AS GrossSale,
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM FinishedTransaction)
  AS counts
FROM finishedsales fs
LEFT JOIN FinishedTransaction ft
  ON fs.TransactionNo = ft.TransactionNo
```

Now, I want to get the quotient of `GrossSale` column and counts column and show it to the third column.. I tried this query below, but it's not working..

```
SELECT
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS FoodServer,
  SUM(Extended * Multiplier) AS GrossSale,
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM FinishedTransaction)
  AS counts,
  (GrossSale / counts) AS result
FROM finishedsales fs
LEFT JOIN FinishedTransaction ft
  ON fs.TransactionNo = ft.TransactionNo
```

This alternative solution is working..

```
SELECT
  SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS FoodServer,
  SUM(Extended * Multiplier) AS GrossSale,
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM FinishedTransaction)
  AS counts,
  SUM(Extended * Multiplier) / (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM FinishedTransaction)
  AS result
FROM finishedsales fs
LEFT JOIN FinishedTransaction ft
  ON fs.TransactionNo = ft.TransactionNo
```

But I don't want that solution because that's a bit wordy, and poor performance. I want to know the best solution for that problem

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with your solution, you may like this better but I doubt you'll get much better performance.

```
Select Foodserver, GrossSale, Counts, (GrossSale / counts) as result    
    FROM
    (
        SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('MachineName') as FoodServer,
        SUM(Extended * Multiplier) as GrossSale, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FinishedTransaction) as counts

        FROM finishedsales fs LEFT JOIN FinishedTransaction ft
        ON fs.TransactionNo = ft.TransactionNo
    ) as salesData
```

nb. you should add divide by zero checking in here too .. I think `where GrossSale <>0 AND Counts <>0` should do it.